# How do I switch to a virtual environment and have Python recognize that Flask is installed?

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I am stumped as I have followed the advice of every forum post I have seen online. I followed the process exactly, and everything looks like it was set up correctly, but Pycharm still won't recognize that I have Flask installed. Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return '<h2>Welcome to my web app</h2>'
```

flask has a squiggly under it and the code fails to launch with an error.

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'"
```

I created a virtual environment called new_env and have activated it using .\new_env\Scripts\activate
However, in Pycharm it still says that the library root is venv which is the default when starting a new project I guess.
[This is my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk6BI.png)

Any advice? I'm trying to get this to work using the Python terminal included with Pycharm but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with terminal. Only by going into actual settings and fumbling through a silly gui.

I tried searching online for how to change the library root using the terminal but couldn't find anything. There should be a way.

Comment: When you say " I followed _the process_ exactly", which process is that? Because regular Python is not the same as PyCharm, so that's pretty important to clarify. Are you talking about the process outlined on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env?

Comment: After activating your env, did you do `python -m pip install flask`?

Comment: In `vscode` whilst you can manually activate any venv in the console, in order for the correct env to be used by the editor (i.e. when linting etc) and debugger etc you have to select it via the vscode `Python: Select Interpreter` command. I'm guessing `pycharm` has something similar?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

```
pythonProject
    |-new_venv
        |- app.py
```

It looks like your app.py is located within your new_env.  It should not be.

**Explanation**

The python virtual environment is a directory to contain a versioned python environment and dependencies for your project/application,  *your own application is not meant to be developed or placed directly within the virtual environment unless you know what you're doing/intending.*

**Steps to Fix**

You can do this to get your configuration back to an expected state:

1. Move your app.py file(s) to the project root.
2. Delete the `new_env` and `venv` directories.  We'll remake them
3. Recreate the `.venv` virtual environment with Pycharm:

   File -> Settings -> Project: name -> Python Interpreter -> Add Interpreter

Your directory should now loosely look like this:

```
pythonProject
    |-.venv
    |- app.py
```

4. Install flask into the virtual environment ".venv".  Reopen the Pycharm terminal.  The input line should begin with *.venv*,  type `pip install flask`

That should be enough for things to be operable.

---

I have written a more detailed write up/guide related to these here, if you're interested:
https://github.com/ZacharyACoon/documentation/blob/main/it/code/python/managing_python_packages_and_your_code.md